# Which memory barrier does glGenerateMipmap require?

Tags: opengl, glsl, memory-barriers, mipmaps

I've written to the first mipmap level of a texture using GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store.  The documentation states that I need to call glMemoryBarrier before I use the contents of this image in other operations, in order to flush the caches appropriately.

For instance, before I do a glTexSubImage2D operation, I need to issue GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT​, and before I issue a draw call using a shader that samples that texture, I need to issue GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT​.

However, which barrier do I need to issue before I am ensured that glGenerateMipmap will use the most recently written data?

Comment: Looks to me like you've found a whole in the spec. I would suggest you contact the spec authors to ask they clarify it.

Comment: As OpenGL 4.5 released there is a new function glTextureBarrier() which expected to do what you want. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTextureBarrier.xhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenGL 4.6 specification clarifies this:

> Any synchronization required before performing this reduction will be done
>   within the `Generate*Mipmap` commands themselves.

So you don't need any kind of synchronization. If you have caused data to be written to the base mipmap level in any way, `glGenerateMipmap` will perform sufficient synchronization to make reads work.

Given that, it's probably a *really* good idea not to call this in the middle of rendering a frame.

Prior specifications had no answer, though information from this bug report suggests that [prior implementations did exactly the above](https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1429).