# Generating the MipMap levels for a 3D texture after imageStore()

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, textures, mipmaps

I want to create a 3D texture, set the lowest (level 0) mipmap level to some data that is generated in shaders, and then auto-populate the rest of the mipmap levels.

I create the texture as follows:

```
//Initialize texture dimensions
width = w;
height = h;
depth = d;
//set the texture rendering target, always GL_TEXTURE3D for 3D images
target = GL_TEXTURE_3D;
//Create the texture
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(target, textureID);
glObjectLabel(GL_TEXTURE, textureID, -1, "\"3D Texture\"");
//Set the texture sampling parameters
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
//Allocate VRAM storage for the texture
vector<GLbyte> empty = vector<GLbyte>(width*height*depth*(32));
glTexImage3D(target, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, depth, 0,
    GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, empty.data());
```

I then write to it in the shaders using imageStore (works as intended for LOD 0).

And then I attempt to generate the mipmap levels like this:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
glGenerateTextureMipmap(textureID);
```

However, this results in a segmentation fault generated right at `glGenerateTextureMipmap()`.

Am I missing a bit in the memory barrier or am I not allocating enough memory when creating the texture? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's up with that `sizeof(GLfloat)` in your `vector` constructor?  If you wanted bytes shouldn't it be a `vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: You are correct, that was my bad, I have changed it and verified that it works with the current version. It was supposed to be 8*4 (number of component swith 8 bytes per component) I messed up, thank you for noticing. The segmentation fault itslef is not gone however

Comment: Are you sure you even _have_ `glGenerateTextureMipmap()`? That's a 4.5 function. Check if that function pointer is actually not NULL.

Comment: @derhass I am running OpenGL 4.6 (ore that's what glGetString() reports at least). Moreover, I called that function in another section and it didn;t segfault. So at least it is not a null pointer.

Comment: For the memory barrier itself, see [Which memory barrier does glGenerateMipmap require?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34072378/2327517). For the crash, I have no idea what could be causing it.

Comment: @NicolBolas correct, My mistake, corrected it.

Comment: You can safely pass a NULL pointer to the glTexImage data parameter. It's always been allowed to do so, to create texture storage without initializing it to specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `glMemoryBarrier` in a wrong way. The bitfield you should give to this function is the way you want to use the result. For mipmap generation, there is no need to use memory barrier.

You are using `glGenerateTextureMipmap`, but you are not using `glCreateTextures`. Why do you want to use DSA only sometimes. Use DSA everywhere or do not use it (the same happen for glTextureParameteri, glTextureStorage3D...).

You are using `glTexImage3D`, use `glTextureStorage3D` instead. It will save you the construction of your "useless" vector

You are using non mipmap filtering, so please use mipmap filtering like `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`. I don't know if it is the cause of the crash, but it is a first idea.

Tell us what happen when you correct the code ;).
Maybe you could give us the output of ARB_DEBUG_OUTPUT if it tells you anything.

---

About the crash, it seems that use `glTexStorage3D` solves the problem. I have no proof and I may be wrong, but I suspect this kind of working :
`glTexImage3D` does not allocate memory, it is the use of the texture that makes the allocation. (That is why I prefer Vulkan, because it is explicit).

so, when you do a `glTexImage3D` without `glGenerateMipmap3D`, here is what happen :

Use `glTexImage3D` : say we need the image at this size. Use the texture : driver see that there is no need for mipmapping, so it allocates only one driver despite the GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL. Call generateMipmap : crash because the driver try to reach the other layers that have not been allocated

Second way, use generateMipmap before use :

`glTexImage3D` + `generateMipmap` : I need one image to this size with mipmap. When you use it, the driver see that you really need all layers so it will allocates the layers needed.

When you are using `glTextureStorage3D` you explicitly ask for the layers, so when the driver makes the allocation, it will allocate everything and not just one

Comment: I can tell you something. Putting the glGenTextureMipmap at the beginning, before the render loop and THEN calling it again solved the segmentation fault.

Also that "useless" vector is not useless. On NVIDIA cards the driver clears the allocated memory, but on AMD cards it does not. My algorithm requires the texture to be initialized to 0. So on AMD cards it breaks. The "empty" vector basically ensures compatibility with AMD cards.

Comment: Also i do not need to call glCreateTextures if I am manually initializing everything through glGenTextures.

Comment: I think your CPU does not care at all about the "initialization" of the texture. Please use glClearTexImage or equivalent to clear in a more efficient way your textures :)

Comment: I know you do not need to call glCreateTextures, however you do not need to call glMemoryBarrier also, but you did it. I just say it to be consistent. You want to use DSA (it is a good thing, but why bother to not use it everytime you can?)

Comment: Quoting the OpenGL Reference glClearTexImage : `If data is NULL, then the pointer is ignored and the sub-range of the texture image is filled with zeros.`  I think it is what you want without building a vector.

Comment: glClearTexImage() is only available since OpenGL 4.4, however I need this to be compatible with opengl 4.2, so I cannot use it (I know generateTextureMipmap is 4.5, I am just trying to get somehting working and I'll edit the backwards compatibility later)

Comment: Okay, I did not know you wanted to be compatible with OpenGL 4.2 since you were using OpenGL 4.5+ functions.

Comment: However what about the filters?

Comment: I need it to be at a single LOD for now. Moroever, it doesn;t seem to eb the problem. Somehow the issue is solved if I call glGenerateTextures() before the main loop and then during the main loop. But segfaults if I only call it during the main loop.

Comment: Maybe a driver bug? Please use glTexStorage3D just for try, and try on another grapid card if you can.

Comment: Huh, it seems glTexStorage indeed solves the problem. Let me check a little bit and I'll get back to you

Comment: It is just an idea, but OpenGL does not say explicitly that the glTexImage will allocate the memory. So if you use gltexImage and use it, you will only allocate the first layer, if you use texImage and GenerateMipmap and after you use it you will allocate all the layers. In glTexStorage3D you explicitly ask for several layers. However it is not just an idea :). Btw, the OpenGL wiki advice to use glTextureStorage and that is why there is no DSA for glTexImage3D.
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture

Comment: Well that seemed to have been the case, thank you. it seems this worked.

Comment: Norrier, you should probably edit your answer a little bit to explain exactly what the issue was now that we know. it would be more helpful to others

Comment: Antoine MORRIER not Norrier please :p. I edited my answer with what we think the error is :).

Comment: I am sorry that was a typo. (Je m'excuse, c'etait pas intentionnel)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176839/discussion-between-antoine-morrier-and-makogan).